# Control is missing from asp.net page but I can see that on page source

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

This issue is really killing me.

I have a page and it has many controls but one control named "Sharepoint:InputFormCustomValidator" is not showing on the page. I can see the control if i do page source but not on the screen. I tried on IE and Chrome and I cant even see that in developer toolbar. Nothing is there on console for developer toolbar as well.

I also checked fiddler to see if something is breaking (404 error) but i don't see anything is breaking.

Comment: It is validator control. You won't see it unless field which it attached to has some validation errors.

Comment: Got the root cause of the problem. I have grid(build with html table) on the page and in this specific condition i have around 2000 rows on the page. I am using telerik Ajax manager to do async postback and when i do that it fails. Looks like Telrik Ajax Manger issue. Still under investigation. BTW thanks a lot for spending time on my issue.